# Query conversion application between SQL databases

Tags: gratis, database, cross-platform

I'm looking for an application that can convert queries, schemas, etc from one SQL-like database (e.g. MySQL) to another (e.g. Oracle). It must be able to support conversion of pretty much everything (like views, procedures, triggers), be free of charge, and it would also be nice if it's cross-platform or a web-application.

Databases I need support for are:

- Oracle
- MySQL
- H2
- Microsoft SQL Server
- SQLite

Comment: When your target is oracle, the oracle migration tool can do it quite well for almost any type of database object. I have not yet seen a tool that is truly database independent in both conversion directions. However when you correctly design the environment you can easily run the same software on most platforms.

Answer (score 1):

This [Oracle Transparent Gateway](http://ceiton.com/CMS/EN/technologies/sql-compiler.html#Solution) from Ceiton goes from MSSQL to Oracle, but I don't know about pricing.

Answer (score 1):

With [RazorSQL](http://razorsql.com), you can [convert schemas from one database to another](http://razorsql.com/docs/how_to_database_conversion.html). I don't know if it'll help you with ad hoc SQL, though. It is not free, but has a 30 day trial.